# Permission declined to write to file

Tags: apache2, php, xampp

On xamppp I have a php script that writes some data that is posted to it, over a text file. But when I try an run it I get [image]

php script :

```
<?php
$file = 'xy.txt';
// Opens the file to load the current content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Adds the data
$current .= "Hello\n";
// Writes the content back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP script?

Comment: Please post text as text, not as an image.

Comment: can you post an output of `cat /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`?

Comment: @AzkerM http://pastebin.com/raw/ns2NV3hK

Comment: See if this command helps: sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste 
root@agar:/opt/lampp/htdocs# sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
chown: cannot access '/var/www': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that file `xy.txt` is not writable by the process that is running the PHP script.

Comment: xampp should be able to write on it

Comment: Can you please post the output of `ls -lap xy.txt` (in the correct directory)?

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 root www-data 0 Jan  2 11:58 xy.txt

Comment: Try a `sudo chown www-data:www-data xy.txt` (in the correct directory).

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a shell, and do the following:

1. `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs`
2. `sudo chown -R :www-data .`
3. `sudo chmod -R 664 .`

That should fix it.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error http://i.imgur.com/5IhnEfL.png

Comment: @DrGoat you're missing the `.`. the `.` indicates the directory to `chown` (which is the current one).

Comment: It should be `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .` and `sudo chmod -R 664 .`

Comment: @dr01 durr, my bad, thanks for catching that. i've updated my answer

Comment: @dr01 - you were so fast... :D ... BTW, @zwork giving permission to the whole `htdocs` ain't a good idea, don't you think?

Comment: @AzkerM it should be fine unless Dr Goat writes some insecure PHP (which is scarily easy to do). Plus, I doubt this is a public XAMPP server

Comment: @AzkerM by doing what you said I'm now getting access denied http://prntscr.com/9lavq8

Comment: @DrGoat pls post the output of `ls -l /opt/lampp/htdocs | grep xy.txt`

Comment: @DrGoat my bad, change the `grep xy.text` to `grep xy.txt`, i've updated my comment

Comment: @zwork -rw-rw-r-- 1 root www-data   0 Jan  2 11:58 xy.txt

Comment: @DrGoat now pls do `cat /opt/lampp/htdocs/xy.txt`

Comment: doing a `cat` to the file has will only show the output and its just a text file which has text strings... this is pretty much permission issues...

Comment: @AzkerM i know that, i'm wondering if it worked (the php script writing to file after he ran the commands in my answer)

Comment: @AzkerM After I ran the command you told me I'm getting error 403

Comment: @DrGoat --- Errgg! feel like you're confused as there are three people currently commenting back and forth... :S

Comment: @AzkerM I am, running this sudo chown -R :www-data .
sudo chmod -R 664 . now does this http://prntscr.com/9lb96s